# How can I reproduce 'Improved GAN' code? Problems with theano/cudnn/docker

Tags: docker, machine-learning, deep-learning, theano, reproducible-research

I've been trying to reproduce the code found [here](https://github.com/openai/improved-gan), with respect to the "Improved GANs" by OpenAI, but I'm having a lot of trouble setting the environment (a Docker container).
I just can't make Theano work properly with this code.

I created a Docker container to test it, but a segmentation fault is raised when I use the stable version of Theano installed using conda...
Some posts suggest to use the development version of Theano instead, but when I update it, Theano can't find the Cudnn anymore

```
(gpuarray/dnn.py", line 98, in _dnn_lib raise RuntimeError('Could not load cudnn library') RuntimeError: Could not load cudnn library)
```

If someone have some background with Theano/lasagne/docker could help me I would appreciate it a lot. If requested I could paste my `Dockerfile`, or anything that could help.

Comment: Please add the `Dockerfile` and the full segmentation fault error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "fix" it using the following [dockerfile](https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.gpu).
Hope it can help someone :)
Apparently, it needed an older Theano version for it to work properly.